# How to find strings between two strings in c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting a string with some patterns, like:

```
A 11 A 222222 B 333 A 44444 B 55 A 66666 B
```

How to get all the strings between A and B in the smallest area?

For example, "A 11 A 222222 B" result in " 222222 "

And the first example should result in:

```
222222 
333 
44444 
55 
66666
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try searching for all regex matches in your input string which are situated between `A` and `B`, or vice-versa.  Here is a regex pattern which uses lookarounds to do this:

```
(?<=\bA )\d+(?= B\b)|(?<=\bB )\d+(?= A\b)
```

Sample script:

```
string input = "A 11 A 222222 B 333 A 44444 B 55 A 66666 B";
var vals = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\bA )\d+(?= B\b)|(?<=\bB )\d+(?= A\b)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
foreach (string val in vals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

This prints:

```
222222
333
44444
55
66666
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made a mistake. Can the result remove 11? I have edited the question. Thx.

Comment: What is the significance of removing `11`?  Is this a value which you want to remove _anywhere_ in the array?  Or, do you want to remove the first number of the array?  Please explain.

Comment: I just want the strings between A and B matched in the smallest area. My input strings may like A..A.+.B..B..A..+..B...A..+..B..B.  I just want +

Comment: @Vincent I fixed my answer.  I missed the part about only picking up on matches between `A..B` or `B..A`.